# INPC-Event shows "ObservableObject.cs not found"

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

The window in the title opens if I change one of my TextBoxes. I am using MVVM Light.

The (test) setup:

**View**

```
<Window ... DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=Main}">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Foo.Bar, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10,10,407,209" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Foo.Bar, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="115,10,302,209" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Foo _foo;

    public Foo Foo
    {
        get
        {
            return _foo;
        }

        set
        {
            Set(() => Foo, ref _foo, value);
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        _foo = new Foo();
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public class Foo : ObservableObject
{
    private string _bar;

    public string Bar
    {
        get { return _bar; }
        set { Set(() => Bar, ref _bar, value); }
    }
}
```

The StackTrace of the error message shows the following:

> Locating source for
>   'd:\GalaSoft\mydotnet\MvvmLight\Source\GalaSoft.MvvmLight\GalaSoft.MvvmLight
>   (NET35)\ObservableObject.cs'. Checksum: MD5 {8e 31 66 ae cd 3b be 8f
>   be e7 3b 2c 73 91 a0 76} The file
>   'd:\GalaSoft\mydotnet\MvvmLight\Source\GalaSoft.MvvmLight\GalaSoft.MvvmLight
>   (NET35)\ObservableObject.cs' does not exist. Looking in script
>   documents for
>   'd:\GalaSoft\mydotnet\MvvmLight\Source\GalaSoft.MvvmLight\GalaSoft.MvvmLight
>   (NET35)\ObservableObject.cs'... Looking in the projects for
>   'd:\GalaSoft\mydotnet\MvvmLight\Source\GalaSoft.MvvmLight\GalaSoft.MvvmLight
>   (NET35)\ObservableObject.cs'. The file was not found in a project.
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   11.0\VC\crt\src\'... Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\crt\src\vccorlib\'... Looking in
>   directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   11.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\'... Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\atlmfc\src\atl\'... Looking in
>   directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   11.0\VC\atlmfc\include'... The debug source files settings for the active solution indicate that the debugger will not ask the user to
>   find the file:
>   d:\GalaSoft\mydotnet\MvvmLight\Source\GalaSoft.MvvmLight\GalaSoft.MvvmLight
>   (NET35)\ObservableObject.cs. The debugger could not locate the source
>   file
>   'd:\GalaSoft\mydotnet\MvvmLight\Source\GalaSoft.MvvmLight\GalaSoft.MvvmLight
>   (NET35)\ObservableObject.cs'.

**Edit**

It hast something to do with the solution context. If I open the project alone everything works. Any further ideas?

Comment: is it reproducible if you add mvvm light via NuGet?

Comment: I added it via NuGet.

Comment: @tkrause, have you tried to add mvvm-light as classic assembly reference?

Comment: Also if the solution file is not so large, could you please add it to the question as well?

Comment: I've checked it without NuGet and it works fine as well. So solution file content might help to figure it out.

Comment: Did an undo unchanged, deleted everything and pulled the latest version into my workspace, recreated the project, installed the NuGet packages and copied over the class files. Now everything works like a charm. Didn't know what the problem was. Maybe I'll face it tomorrow again? I don't know but for the moment it works...

Comment: @tkrause, sounds like we have a [Heisenbug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug) here :)

Comment: Haha. Maybe we have found one... ;-) Anyway thank you for your effort!

Comment: where does the "Set" Method in your set-accessor come from?
Set(() => Bar, ref _bar, value);

I know that you already solved it, but is there the name missing to what property the textbox is binded to? (in the view)

Comment: Set comes from the inheritance of ViewModelBase.